# How to use ESC/POS commands to print QR code

Tags: qr-code

I'm trying to print qrcode using esc/pos commands.
Text I want to print is 'ABCD'
Printer is Bixolon srp E300

According to command manual , my code looks like this:

```
  init := chr(27) || chr(64);

center := chr(27) || 'a1';

fn165 := chr(29) || '(k' || chr(4) || chr (0) || chr(49) || chr(65) || chr(50) || chr(0) ;

fn167 := chr(29) ||'(k30' || chr(49) || chr(67) ||      chr(5);

fn180 := chr(29) || '(k' || chr(7) || chr(0) || chr(49) || chr(80) || chr(48) || chr(65) || chr(66) || chr(67) || chr(68);

fn181 := chr(29) || '(k30'   || chr(49) ||  chr(81) || chr(48) ;

all := fn165 || fn167 || fn180 || fn181;
call print (init);
call print (center);
call print (all);
```

And my print output looks like in the picture..

But when I try to scan qr code, I get an empty string ( no text).

I suppose that something is wrong with my fn180 line so I tried to modify it:

```
fn180 := chr(29) || '(k' || '07' || '00' || chr(49) || chr(80) || chr(48) || chr(65) || chr(66) || chr(67) || chr(68);
```

But I still got the same output.

When I changed fn180 to

```
fn180 := chr(29) || '(k' || '7' || '0' || chr(49) || chr(80) || chr(48) || chr(65) || chr(66) || chr(67) || chr(68);
```

my printer freezes..

What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Dubravko, did you resolve your problem with printing QR code?